# Does Elastigirl leave her baby in the car by himself?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-incredibles

Notice during the “tack scene” in the principal’s office, Helen is not holding Jack Jack:

[image]

Then, in the next scene, while Dash is begging to play sports, Jack Jack is quietly sitting in the back seat:

[image]

As far as we know, the Parrs had no friends (presumably b/c they were superheroes in hiding) and did not use a babysitter.  (Kari did not come along till Violet hired her to watch Jack Jack so she and Dash could hitch a ride on the Jet.)

Helen is a very loving, protective mother; so where was Jack Jack while she was in the principal’s office?

Comment: I know school office staff who would be delighted to look after / dote-on a baby for a few minutes whilst you talk to the Principal.

Comment: Probably a movie goof - http://www.moviemistakes.com/film4565

Comment: @iandotkelly - I agree. My wife went to her hairdresser the other day and the receptionists were only too happy to look after our daughter while mom had her hair done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[I'd say that iandotkelly actually answered this in the comments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/does-elastigirl-leave-her-baby-in-the-car-by-himself#comment4648_3019).

The most likely thing that happened is that Helen had someone in the receptionist office watch Jack Jack while the principal had a serious discussion with her about Dash, since babies can be very distracting to such a talk. It's quite common for parents to bring their younger kids with them to parent teacher conferences. This probably wasn't shown or animated because it's such a normal thing for parents that it wouldn't even register that Jack Jack isn't with her.